# BIML - Can you assign an include file to a variable?

Tags: ssis, biml

I am trying to move common bit of an SQLs into separate files.
How can I then retrieve the file and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some `C#` or `VB` scripting to read the contents of the file and return it to be used within your Biml.

This is very simple to do assuming you know the location of your file.  In `C#`:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\SQLFiles\MySQLFile.sql");
```